# Shorter way to Declare and Initialize List<ushort>

Tags: c#, list, ushort

Currently, I am declaring and initializing a list like this:

```
List<ushort> myList = new List<ushort>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

I will eventually have more `ushort` lists that will contain a lot more than 10 values and it's inefficient to type out every number between 1-100, for example. The list will always be a range of numbers.

Is there a shorter way to write this?  I have tried researching `Enumerable.Range`, but that only handles `int` values and I receive a "Cannot implicitly convert type int to ushort" error.

Comment: Use a for loop? Enumerable.Range(...).ToList() ?

Comment: If you're going to be making "more ushort lists", it sounds like it's going to be repeated a lot. I'd suggest you make your own static factory method that takes your lower and upper bounds to produce the list and have all your code use that factory method. That way if you want to introduce a more verbose, but more efficient method of building the list later, or if you change your mind about using LINQ or _whatever_ it doesn't matter because you aren't repeating yourself; change it in one spot and everyone is happy and your calling code is simpler for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about an explicit cast?

```
List<ushort> myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => (ushort)i).ToList();
```

and then make it really short!

```
var myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => (ushort)i).ToList();
```

Comment: `List<ushort> myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => (ushort)i).GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(x => x).Select(x => x).ToList();`  :P

Comment: `Cast<>` won't work here. It's not designed to handle that sort of conversion. It's designed for identity conversions and reference conversions, basically. (I believe that prior to a service pack it *would* have worked here, but that was a long time ago.)

Comment: @sircodesalot: `Select` is the right approach, because it *works*.

Comment: Crap, you're right. : / That's what I get for trying to be funny.

Comment: That is exactly what I need, thanks! Could you explain the ".Select(i => (ushort)i)"? Assuming it sets 'i' as the int parameter and then you cast it to ushort?

Comment: @McRealz: Rather than explaining this specific case, I suggest you read up on LINQ, and learn the general case. If you haven't used LINQ before, it'll be a real treat :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: thanks for the comment about cast, I was just trying it out and got the "nice" runtime `InvalidCastException` error, without a compile time warning.

Comment: @AndyBrown: You wouldn't get a compile-time warning - it's entirely valid at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a loop to fill your list.

```
List<ushort> myList = new List<ushort>();
```

And then have this in a method:

```
ushort count = 100; //or whatever number you need

for (ushort i = 1; i < count + 1; i++)
    myList.Add(i);
```

One advantage to a loops, imo, is that if you in the future have a list of something, like classes, you can easily create different instances of the classes in the loop and add them to the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ushort> values= Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => (ushort) x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A version of `Enumerable.Range` using .NET 7's new [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) functionality could be:

```cs
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Range<T>(T start, T count)
        where T : INumber<T>
    {
        for (T i = start; i < count; i++)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Used like

```cs
ushort[] range = EnumerableEx.Range<ushort>(0, 1000).ToArray();
```